# using pointers inside functions

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

Why is it that everytime you declare pointer parameter inside the function and start to use it inside the function, you need to use asterisk next to the pointer variable everytime you use it somehow in the function. Why is it that way?

Comment: If you want to get the value that the pointer (*any* pointer) is pointing to then you must dereference the pointer, as in `*pointer_variable`. Otherwise you work on the pointer variable itself.

Comment: That's not restricted to function parameters, local (and global) pointer variables work the same way

Comment: Short answer: because C is not C++, and does not have reference types.

Comment: How would you ever distinguish between the pointer variable and the memory pointed to?

Answer (score 0):

If you come from a language like Java, where you do:

```
AbstractBeanFactorySingletonStubWrapper w = new MyBeanFactorySingletonStubWrapper();
```

You basically see that the only things you can do with the `w` reference, besides dereference it (e.g. call methods), is to test it against `null`.

That is trivial enough that you don't need any extra syntax to work with references.

In C and C++, however, you can have the following:

```
int val[] = {5, 6};
int *p = val;
(*p)++;
p++;
```

There is a critical difference between `(*p)++` and `p++`: the former operates on the value, like in Java, whereas the latter operates on the pointer.

In summary, because C and C++ allow you to do many more things with pointers than languages like Java and C#, pointers require some kind of extra syntax.

You could ask "why not make dereference the "easy" syntax (like in Java) and require the extra syntax for these other pointer operations?". I don't know for sure, but but the very act of dereferencing a pointer, without any further operation on it, is its own an operation (which could segfault), so it seems appropriate to give it the extra syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how pointers work in C - to access the pointed-to object, you *dereference* the pointer using the unary `*` operator.

It's not automatic because sometimes you want to work with the pointer value itself.